# Apply accumulated sum to a series of pandas.df

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Recently, I try to find an efficient way to do accumulated sum on a series.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['a']=[1,3,1,4,2,5,3,8]
>>> df
       a
    0  1
    1  3
    2  1
    3  4
    4  2
    5  5
    6  3
    7  8
```

The expected output :

```
df
       a  b
    0  1  1
    1  3  4
    2  1  5
    3  4  9
    4  2  11
    5  5  16
    6  3  19
    7  8  27
```

Each `b[i]` equals `sum(a[j] for j<=i)`

I deal with the problem by

```
df['b']=df.a
for i in range(df.shape[0]-1):
    df.b.ix[i+1]+=df.b.ix[i] if df.b.ix[i+1] else df.b.ix[i]
```

It's not concise enough, I want to take off the loop.
Here I come for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['b'] = df.a.cumsum()
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html